# XSLT - comparing and combining two XML Files

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, compare

I have one quite complex XML file and one simpler which contains some corrections for the complex one.

One element from the complex one:

```mxml
<h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020528">
      <h1:Block Type="obj"
                CreationDate="20.03.2014 09:39:50"
                CreatorID="Admin"
                ChangeDate="21.01.2015 14:40:51"
                ChangerID="Admin"
                OwnerID="Admin"
                FieldsCount="17">
         <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="40020528"/>
         <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
            <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="unbekannt"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
            <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="Köln"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2900"
                      Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="TWS_FGL00541"/>
            <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="No: 4260"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
            <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="unbekannt"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="Theater"/>
            <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="Theater unbekannt"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
            <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
            <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Fotograf/in, Atelier"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
            <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="unbekannt"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Autor/in"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
            <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
            <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regie"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
            <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
            <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
         </h1:Field>
         <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="Fritz Feinhals"/>
         <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="Fotografie"/>
         <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="Negativ"/>
         <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="Glasplattennegativ"/>
         <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="18x13"/>
         <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="Feinhals, Fritz"/>
      </h1:Block>
   </h1:Document>
```

One element from the simple one:

```mxml
<signatur id="TWS_FGL00541">
      <datum/>
      <ort/>
      <ortsteil/>
      <titel>Fritz Feinhals als Wotan</titel>
      <fotograf/>
      <komponist>Wagner, Richard</komponist>
      <author/>
      <regie/>
      <buehnenbild/>
      <darPerson/>
      <freiText>Walküre</freiText>
   </signatur>
```

I'm trying to compare the elements of the two documents per "Signatur". if the signatures are same, then there is a correction. If there is a correction, it has to be checked which child elements from simpler XML have to put in the child elements of the complex one, so it has to be checked if child elements of the simple one have a value in it, and if its so, the value must placed in specific Element in the complex one.

I have no idea, what is the best approach to do that. I was trying something like as follows:

```mxml
<xsl:template name="alles" match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="Halft" select="document('simpleOne.xml')" />

<xsl:variable name="Sig_Halft" select="preceding-sibling::$Halft/document/signatur" />
<xsl:variable name="Sig_HiDA" select="preceding-sibling::DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob28']/Field[@Type='2950']/@Value" />


<!-- <xsl:variable name="" select="" /> -->

<xsl:template match="DocumentSet/Document">
    <xsl:if test="$Sig_HiDA = $Sig_Halft"> <!-- wenn signatur gleich -->
        xcbcvncvn
        <!-- Datum -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5060']/Field[@Type='5064']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5060']/Field[@Type='5064']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/datum))">

        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Ort -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob26']/Field[@Type='2664']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob26']/Field[@Type='2664']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/ort))">

        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Ortsteil(Theater) -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob26']/Field[@Type='2700']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob26']/Field[@Type='2700']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/ortsteil))">

        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Titel -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5200']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5200']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/titel))">
            <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="{$Halft/document/signatur/titel}"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Fotograf -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob30']/Field[@Type='3100']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='ob30']/Field[@Type='3100']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/fotograf))">

        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Komponist -->
        <xsl:if test="((DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5007']/Field[@Type='5009']/@Value != '') or (DocumentSet/Document/Block/Field[@Type='5007']/Field[@Type='5009']/@Value != $Halft/document/signatur/komponist))">

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your sample input XML and your sample XSL code show no immediate relationship -- nothing in your XSL will match anything in your XML.  Please read the [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and revise your post accordingly.

Comment: thank you for advice, but i have to say that i cant understand how they dont show immediate relationship. how can you assume nothing in my xsl will match anything in my XML? You can see in variables and if statements that i have the expressions for the elements from the both XML-Files. From my revise after i saw your comment, i can only say that i just didnt mention in the example xml files that they have parent elements "DocumentSet" for complex one and "Document" for the simple one, which hold the Objects (or elements) shown above.

Comment: Re: not matching: `DocumentSet/Document` wouldn't match anything because 1) there is no `DocumentSet` element in your sample input XML, so there would be no `Document` children; and 2) even if we just match on `Document` in the default namespace, your input XML has only `h1:Document` in a non-default namespace, and these two are not equivalent.  Namespaces and prefixes are important, and tricky, parts of XML processing.  If you work with XML much, it might benefit you to read up on these.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template name="identity" match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="rework" select="document('simpleOne.xml')" />

    <!-- matching all documents that have a counterpart in 'simpleOne.xml'; others will be copied as is -->
    <xsl:template match="*:Document[.//*:Field[@Type='2950']/@Value=$rework//*:signatur/@id]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <!-- handing over the current snippet/node from 'simpleOne.xml' -->
                <xsl:with-param name="currentMergeInfo" select="$rework//*:signatur[@id = current()//*:Field[@Type='2950']/@Value]" as="node()" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- templates for actual replacement of the values -->
    <xsl:template match="*:Field[@Type='3475']">
        <xsl:param name="currentMergeInfo" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($currentMergeInfo = '')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @Value"/>
                    <!-- outputting the new value -->
                    <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentMergeInfo//*:fotograf"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>        
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- if the parameter is an empty string just copy what is already there -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms your (slightly extended) input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h1:DocumentSet xmlns:h1="someNamespace">
    <h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020528">
        <h1:Block Type="obj"
            CreationDate="20.03.2014 09:39:50"
            CreatorID="Admin"
            ChangeDate="21.01.2015 14:40:51"
            ChangerID="Admin"
            OwnerID="Admin"
            FieldsCount="17">
            <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="40020528"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
                <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
                <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2900"
                    Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="TWS_FGL00541"/>
                <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="No: 4260"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
                <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="Theater"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="Theater unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Fotograf/in, Atelier"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Autor/in"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regie"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="Fritz Feinhals"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="Fotografie"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="Negativ"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="Glasplattennegativ"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="18x13"/>
            <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="Feinhals, Fritz"/>
        </h1:Block>
    </h1:Document>
    <h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020528">
        <h1:Block Type="obj"
            CreationDate="20.03.2014 09:39:50"
            CreatorID="Admin"
            ChangeDate="21.01.2015 14:40:51"
            ChangerID="Admin"
            OwnerID="Admin"
            FieldsCount="17">
            <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="someValue"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
                <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
                <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="somePlace"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2900"
                    Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="sampleID"/>
                <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="someNumber"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
                <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="someEntity"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="someEntity"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Fotograf/in, Atelier"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Autor/in"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regie"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="someName"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="someType"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="someFormat"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="someSpecification"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="someFormat"/>
            <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="someName"/>
        </h1:Block>
    </h1:Document>
</h1:DocumentSet>
```

based on `simpleOne.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<signaturen>
    <signatur id="TWS_FGL00541">
        <datum/>
        <ort/>
        <ortsteil/>
        <titel>Fritz Feinhals als Wotan</titel>
        <fotograf/>
        <komponist>Wagner, Richard</komponist>
        <author/>
        <regie/>
        <buehnenbild/>
        <darPerson/>
        <freiText>Walküre</freiText>
    </signatur>
    <signatur id="sampleID">
        <datum/>
        <ort/>
        <ortsteil/>
        <titel>sample title</titel>
        <fotograf>sample photographer</fotograf>
        <komponist>sample composer</komponist>
        <author/>
        <regie/>
        <buehnenbild/>
        <darPerson/>
        <freiText>sample text</freiText>
    </signatur>
</signaturen>
```

into the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h1:DocumentSet xmlns:h1="someNamespace">
    <h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020528">
        <h1:Block Type="obj" CreationDate="20.03.2014 09:39:50" CreatorID="Admin" ChangeDate="21.01.2015 14:40:51" ChangerID="Admin" OwnerID="Admin" FieldsCount="17">
            <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="40020528"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
                <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
                <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2900" Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="TWS_FGL00541"/>
                <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="No: 4260"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
                <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="Theater"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="Theater unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="Max Muster"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Autor/in"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regie"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="Fritz Feinhals"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="Fotografie"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="Negativ"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="Glasplattennegativ"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="18x13"/>
            <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="Feinhals, Fritz"/>
        </h1:Block>
    </h1:Document>
    <h1:Document DocKey="obj     40020528">
        <h1:Block Type="obj" CreationDate="20.03.2014 09:39:50" CreatorID="Admin" ChangeDate="21.01.2015 14:40:51" ChangerID="Admin" OwnerID="Admin" FieldsCount="17">
            <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="someValue"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5060" Value="Aufnahme">
                <h1:Field Type="5064" Value="unbekannt"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob28" Value="Verwalter">
                <h1:Field Type="2864" Value="somePlace"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2900" Value="Theaterwissenschaftliche Sammlung, Universität zu Köln"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2930" Value="Fotoabteilung"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2950" Value="sampleID"/>
                <h1:Field Type="907d" Value="someNumber"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob26" Value="Aufnahmeort">
                <h1:Field Type="2664" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2690" Value="someEntity"/>
                <h1:Field Type="2700" Value="someEntity"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob30" Value="Herstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="3100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="3475" Value="sample photographer"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5007" Value="Darstellung">
                <h1:Field Type="5009" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5010" Value="Autor/in"/>
                <h1:Field Type="5013" Value="xTITELx"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Regie"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="ob40" Value="Inszenierung">
                <h1:Field Type="4100" Value="unbekannt"/>
                <h1:Field Type="4475" Value="Bühnenbild"/>
            </h1:Field>
            <h1:Field Type="5200" Value="someName"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5220" Value="someType"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5230" Value="someFormat"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5240" Value="someSpecification"/>
            <h1:Field Type="5360" Value="someFormat"/>
            <h1:Field Type="55th" Value="someName"/>
        </h1:Block>
    </h1:Document>
</h1:DocumentSet>
```

So far, this transformation only cares about the field with `@type="3475"` as I could easily map this to the new value. The idea is to create similar templates for the other children of `signatur`.

---

**Note**: I wrapped two `h1:Document` nodes in `h1:DocumentSet` in case you need to process several "documents" at once. Similarly, I created a wrapper element in `simpleOne.xml`. It should be easy to remove this if you process the files one by one. Also, I foolproofed the namespaces with wildcards – that is definitely no best practice, try to use them properly.

Comment: @EnesteziAbdelQader: Important caveat: user9775's code uses the XSL 2.0+ technique of `*:Document` to work around the absence of prefix and namespace information in your sample input XML.  This technique only works correctly if 1) your XSL processor supports XSL 2.0+, and 2) all your `Document`, `Field`, etc. elements are found in only one namespace (i.e. all with the same prefix, assuming that would be `h1` from your sample input).  If you have some `Document` elements with the `h1` prefix, and other `Document` elements with any other prefix, this code will not produce the expected output.